# Skip first four lines using BufferedReader

Tags: android, bufferedreader, skip

For an App I am developing, I have a text file which I want to read using BufferedReader. The first four lines in the text file or not relevant though, so I do not want to read those. I looked at the documentation on BufferedReader, and I saw that I can use BufferedReader.skip(bytes) where I enter the amount of bytes to skip. However, the first four lines in the text file won't always contain the same amount of information so I think this is not really suitable for my purposes. Do you guys have an idea how to approach this some more practical way?

Comment: just read first four lines and throw them away

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int lineNumber = 0;
while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
    if (++lineNumber < 4)
        continue;

    // process next line
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know how long the lines are the only way to skip 4 lines is reading them and not using the results.